# Subjective case or objective case?

Tags: word-usage, pronouns

When translating a sentence like "It has been you." in Italian, should I use the subjective case for *you*, or the objective case?

In other words, should I say *sei stato tu* or *sei stato te*?

I would use *sei stato te*, but it sounds strange to my hears. I interpret is as *tu sei stato* for which the subject is then moved at the end of the sentence. Is it correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

“Sei stato te” is an ungrammatical sentence, “te” being the objective-case form, to be used only as the direct or indirect object of a verb (“(non ho visto Gianni,) ho visto te”, “(non l'ho dato a Maria,) l'ho dato a te”), and even so, mostly when you want to put the stress on “you” (otherwise you'd say “ti ho visto”, “te l'ho dato”).

By the way, in a sentence like “sei stato tu”, “tu” is actually the subject.

(This said, it is not too uncommon to hear people using “te” in the above ungrammatical way.)

Answer (score 4):

The correct form is

> Sei stato tu?

as *tu* is the subject of the phrase and it's grammatically equivalent to

> Tu sei stato?

even though with a significant different emphasis and meaning.

However it's not uncommon tu use *te* in place of *tu* in such a phrase. Many native speakers would say

> Sei stato te?

probably without even being aware of its incorrectness.

So it's still incorrect, but it's surely very used and - personally - it doesn't particularly bother me when I hear it.